# Multiple brush charts with Apexcharts in VueJs

Tags: javascript, vue.js, apexcharts

I'm developing an application where I'm using apex charts to create a [brush chart](https://apexcharts.com/vue-chart-demos/line-charts/brush-chart/). However, I want my brush to control multiple charts instead a single one, as the example shows.
Before I start working with callbacks I'm wondering if there is an easy-way of make this work with that library, for example by passing an array of targets:

```
brush:{
   target: 'chart2',
   enabled: true
 },
```

Thanks in advance,

Answer (score 0):

I think this might be undocumented, but apparently apexcharts lets you define this:

```
brush: { enabled: true, targets: ['candles', 'candles_2nd'] },
```

I found in the lib-code that it actually handles it like this:

```
var targets = w.config.chart.brush.targets || [w.config.chart.brush.target]; // retro compatibility with single target option
```

Regards,
Jim